# How to return IE.LocationUrl where characters are appended after login?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have a VBA code that scrapes data from a web page that requires login credentials.

The sequence is as follows:

1. Open Web page (http://itpc.sdc.bsnl.co.in:7777/pls/apex/f?p=204:1)
2. Input credentials and click 'Login'
   3.Once logged in, the url changes to
   (http://itpc.sdc.bsnl.co.in:7777/pls/apex/f?p=124:783409349409959)

Note the final part of the latter url has a random number which is constant for the entire session.

I need this number or the url to do further processing, so I use IE.LocationUrl after logging in, and save it in a string for further use.

The code works with IE6, but with newer versions of IE, the IE.LocationUrl property does not fetch the POST LOGIN URL, but instead shows the base Url, which is http://itpc.sdc.bsnl.co.in:7777/pls/apex/f?p=204:1.

```vb
Sub scrape()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim baseurl As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Navigate "http://itpc.sdc.bsnl.co.in:7777/pls/apex/f?p=204:1"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.document.getElementbyId("P101_USERNAME").Value = "b200800935"
    ie.document.getElementbyId("P101_PASSWORD").Value = "xxxxxxxx"

    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    For Each l In ie.document.getElementsbyTagName("a")
        If l.className = "t20Button" Then
            l.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'baseurl = Replace(ie.LocationUrl, "204", "124")
    MsgBox ie.LocationUrl
    'MsgBox Replace(ie.LocationUrl, "204", "124") & "::NO::HOME_APP,HOME_PAGE:204,1"

    'ie.Navigate Replace(ie.LocationUrl, "204", "124") & "::NO::HOME_APP,HOME_PAGE:204,1"
    'ie.Navigate "http://www.google.co.in"

    'Do While ie.Busy
    'DoEvents
    'Loop
    '
    'ie.document.getElementbyId("PHONE_NO").Value = "04565-282200"
    'ie.document.getElementbyId("P1_GO").Click
    '
    'Do While ie.Busy
    'DoEvents
    'Loop
    '
    'For Each l In ie.document.getElementsbyTagName("a")
    'If l.innerText = "04565-282200" Then
    'l.Click
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next
    '
    'Do While ie.Busy
    'DoEvents
    'Loop
    '
    ''ie.Quit
    ''Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note the following line where I check the post-login Url through MsgBox. It does not show that unique number at the end, but the actual Url before login. However, the web page is logged in and I can access the page manually.

```vb
For Each l In ie.document.getElementsbyTagName("a")
    If l.className = "t20Button" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

MsgBox ie.LocationUrl
```

Again, this works with my old computer with IE6 but it does not with newer versions. (I am trying in Windows 10/ IE 11).
Only with the POST-LOGIN URL can I access further data.

Comment: The above URL is company specific and cannot be accessed through Internet. FYI.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the html itself that this URL is present? If so, can you grab it from there?

Comment: Didd you try `ie.document.url`?